# Why nohup failed to keep ssh-agent process alive out of session?

Tags: session, ssh, nohup

When I write .bashrc script to hold pubkey passphrase, the most important command is:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

The problem is, if the session exits, ssh-agent will be closed automatically which leads to the need of entering passphrase again in the next session. What I want is to set passphrase only once until the system reboot. Therefore I try:

```
eval `nohup ssh-agent -s`
```

Hope ssh-agent can live out of starting session like other long run processes. However, it does NOT work... Why? And how to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance.

FYI, the whole script is:

```
ssh-reagent() {
  for agent in $TMPDIR/ssh-*/agent.*; do
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$agent
    if ssh-add -l &> /dev/null; then
      echo "Found working SSH Agent:"
      ssh-add -l
      return
    else
      rm -rf $(dirname ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK})
      export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=
    fi
  done
  eval `ssh-agent -s`  # <-- How to keep ssh-agent alive when logout?
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
}
ssh-reagent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Wrong approach! Instead you just have to take care *where* you start the ssh-agent. You should not do it for each and every shell you start, but only once for the login shell. That one spawns all other processes of a user, so the agent will be available in all until the user logs out again.

Typical places are:

- `/etc/X11/xdm/sys.xsession` or `~/.xsession` for a graphical login
- `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` for a normal login shell

This depends a bit on your distribution and your personal preferences.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, my code is from re-agent script. Let me show the whole thing in my post.

Comment: Sorry, but the script you added to the question is _not_ the ssh-reagent script, it is a modified version. The original comes without the call to `ssh-agent` which is where you introduce the issue. My answer still applies, I'd say. Just as the documentation explains: the ssh-agent should exist already, only then you can re-attach to it. Spawning a new one each time simply does not make any sense.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference. I should put ssh-agent line in ~/.bash_profile and put ssh-reagent in ~/.bashrc. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, that goes into the right direction. Though I am not sure that covers your use cases. Typically a new shell you open from an existing session on a system already has access to the agent. You only need something like this approach when you open a second session (not a second shell!) on a system where you already have one. So it is about login processes in both cases. Example: you start the ssh-agent with your XSession and then additionally connect via ssh from outside to the same system. In that case the script allows to reuse the already running agent in the additional logins.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work. OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 with default bash. The failure comes from two aspect. #1 ~/.bash_profile is executed every time when I login, and this file calls ~/.bashrc also. Therefore it's equivalent to my code. #2 The most weird thing is why nohup can not hold ssh-agent process but ok for other processes?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Thank you.